# How can one make RStudio pass options to Sweave()?

Tags: xetex, unicode, r, sweave, rstudio

I'm trying to use a UTF-8 encoded .Rnw file in combination with xelatex in RStudio. Since xelatex uses native UTF-8 support i cannot use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in my .Rnw file, which would ensure that the encoding auto-guessing of Sweave() works properly. The only other option I know of is to run

```
Sweave(..., encoding="utf8")
```

however, I don't know how to configure RStudio to call `Sweave()` that way. Is there an option in RStudio for that, or any other way to pre-set this option for Sweave?

Comment: You can customize markdown rendering http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering , but I don't know/don't think this is available for Sweave/PDF rendering. It might be worth opening an issue on the RStudio forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Sweave guesses the file encoding from `\usepackage[foo]{inputenc}`, RStudio does not guess, because it is an editor, and it knows the encoding *precisely*. In fact, RStudio just passes the encoding to `utils::Sweave()` directly, so you are totally fine without `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` when using XeLaTeX. You need to make sure you are using the latest version of RStudio, since I do not remember which version of RStudio this feature was added to (but I'm pretty sure the latest version has it). The same thing is applied to `knitr`, which does not guess the encoding at all.

Comment: indeed it passes that correctly, thanks! Sneaked in some ad for your tool, ha? :-) totally have to take a look at that. Still stuck btw, doing utf-8 stuff in R on windows seems to be kind of a bad idea due to windows and locales... :-(

Comment: @barbaz yes, ads added because I think it is a bad idea to guess the encoding; you are also right that Windows is the hell of encodings.